# How to Iterate Group of Data and Return as List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, material-ui

I have a data like this

```
0: {rowid: "4b531532a5a9", groups: "Group1", descriptions: "Item1"......}
1: {rowid: "e55315ccabb5", groups: "Group2", descriptions: "Item2"......}
2: {rowid: "f27135283089", groups: "Group1", descriptions: "Item3"......}
```

I need to show it like this https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fwi6f?file=/demo.js

So First, when I get the data from API, first I do below (groupBy is a lodash method that goes thru data and groups by property)

```
let list = groupBy(response.data, "groups");
      this.setState({
        Groups: Object.keys(list),
        BackOffice: response.data,
      });
```

This way I get all group names and data saved into state. Then I have below code so far to create a full list but I am not sure why it doesn't work..

```
GetBackOffice = () => {
    return (
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <List dense style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }}>
          {this.GetList()}
        </List>
      </Grid>
    );
  };

  GetList = () => {
    let list = "";
    this.state.Groups &&
      this.state.Groups.map((EachGroup) => {
        let CurrentData = this.state.BackOffice.filter(
          (row) => row.groups === EachGroup
        );
        list += CurrentData.map((row) => (
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemText primary="1" />
            <ListItemSecondaryAction>
              <IconButton edge="end" aria-label={row.descriptions}>
                <DownloadIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </ListItemSecondaryAction>
          </ListItem>
        ));
      });

    return list;
  };
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the groupBy returned object directly instead of filtering each time per group?  And you shouldn't be using map if you aren't using its return value.  And list is a string.  You should be using an array of components

Comment: groupBy returns objects, I turn it into array so I can map easier. The last point is right, so I am not sure how to do it so I can get the result I need.

Comment: You also didn't fill in any data in the list except with hardcoded values and aria-label with descriptions.  Is that deliberate?

Comment: Well, I'll make them links etc, but for now I wanted to display them at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-w5dl3
Using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to flatten the array while mapping

```
GetList = () =>
  this.state.Groups &&
  this.state.Groups.flatMap(EachGroup => {
    let CurrentData = this.state.BackOffice.filter(
      row => row.groups === EachGroup
    );
    return CurrentData.map(row => (
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemText primary="1" />
        <ListItemSecondaryAction>
          <IconButton edge="end" aria-label={row.descriptions}>
            <DownloadIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </ListItem>
    ));
  });
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-x7edo
I would recommend using the groupBy returned object directly with [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) (Or Object.entries()) and not filtering each time by key:

```
  GetData = () => {
    const Groups = groupBy(response.data, "groups");
    this.setState({
      Groups
    });
  };

  GetList = () =>
    this.state.Groups &&
    Object.values(this.state.Groups).map(CurrentData => {
      return CurrentData.map(row => (
        <ListItem key={row.rowid}>
          <ListItemText primary="1" />
          <ListItemSecondaryAction>
            <IconButton edge="end" aria-label={row.descriptions}>
              <DownloadIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </ListItemSecondaryAction>
        </ListItem>
      ));
    });
```